# Number of string permutations that are palindromes

Tags: code-golf, string, combinatorics, permutations, palindrome

Your input will be a string consisting of small english letters.

Your task is to determine the number of distinct permutations of the original string that are a palindrome.

The input string has up to 100 letters. In the case of a longer string the result might be very big so the output should be the number of permutations modulo 666013.

For example,

```
cababaa -> 3
```

The possible permutations are:

```
aabcbaa
abacaba
baacaab
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer wins!

Comment: "Given that the string has up to 100 digits the result must be %666013." If so, it would be a good idea to include a corresponding test case.

Comment: For future reference [the sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) sometimes works wonders

Comment: I don't understand the %666013 line. This is a promising challenge, though, and I'd be willing to vote to reopen once that's explained.

Comment: Oh, now that's been edited, I see what you're getting at. I don't think that line adds to the challenge; it mostly just punishes languages without arbitrary-precision integers. Normally we do something like "the answer should be correct if run in a hypothetical version of your language with unbounded integers".

Comment: This could really use more test-cases.

Comment: Suggestions for test-cases (please verify them though): `abcdabcddddd -> 120` *(no odd character count)*, `abcdabcdddddd -> 120` *(one odd character count)*, `abcdabcddddddeee -> 0` *(two odd character counts)*, `aabbccddeeffgghhiijj -> 298735` *(affected by the modulo)*.

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (2), 15 bytes

```
{p.↔}ᶠdl%₆₆₆₀₁₃
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@19doPeobUrtw20LUnJUHzW1wVDDo6bGR03N//8rJScmAWGi0v8oAA)

### Explanation

```
{p.↔}ᶠdl%₆₆₆₀₁₃
{   }ᶠdl          Count (l) the number of distinct (d) results (ᶠ) obtainable by:
 p                  permuting {the input}
  .                 to produce an output
   ↔                that, if reversed, is still the output
        %₆₆₆₀₁₃   then take that number modulo 666013
```

Comment: I definitely need to implement that "find unique"...

Comment: @Fatalize: Yes! I think even "count unique" happens often enough in challenges to maybe be worth a 1-byte representation. On the other hand, "modulo 666013" almost certainly doesn't ;-)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>17</s> <s>16</s> 13 bytes

*-1 byte from Jonathon Allan*

*-3 bytes from Emigna and Adnan*

```
œÙvyÂQO•E›j•%
```

Explanation:

```
œÙ                # Unique permutations of [implicit] input
  vy              # For each permutation...
    ÂQ            # Check if it is a palindrome
      O           # If so, increment the counter
       •E›j•%     # Modulo 666013 (no clue why this number, or even why this rule is in place)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@3908uGZZZWHmwL9HzUscn3UsCsLSKv@/5@cmASEiQA)

Comment: It seems to work without either of the `}`s. I'm not entirely sure it'll work for all string that way though.

Comment: You can use `•E›j•` in place of `666013` to save a byte (it's a base compression).

Comment: @JonathanAllan mind if you explain how that works? I haven't used that feature in 05AB1E before :)

Comment: The content, `E›j`, represents the digits `[14, 116, 45]` which are converted from base `214`, and becomes `14*214^2 + 116*214 + 45 = 666013`. I'm not quite sure where the reference is for the digits, but they seem to be in line (ish?) with their order on the [info page](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/Info.txt). @Adnan may enlighten us.

Comment: @JonathanAllan: They are in the order: `digits/uppercase_letters/lowercase_letters/other_ascii/non_ascii`. If you want the specific order it can be found as a string in the baseconvert functions [here](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/commands.py)

Comment: @Emigna thanks so much! I had not dug down - I found the value quite quickly and once asked just evaluated the single `•x•` values.

Comment: @JonathanAllan: Good thinking! Easiest way is just doing it [programatically](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@29mZmZgaKxgZGji9P9/cmISECYCAA)

Comment: @Emigna Easy when you know the language :D

Comment: You can save 2 bytes removing the if-statement as you only have the needed values on stack anyways: `œÙvyÂQ}O•E›j•%`

Comment: @JonathanAllan: True. Your way was more impressive though :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan The full range of digits (and characters) can be found [here](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/commands.py#L53) :).

Comment: Building on @Emigna's comment, you can save another byte by removing the closing bracket: [`œÙvyÂQO•E›j•%`](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@3908uGZZZWHmwL9HzUscn3UsCsLSKv@/5@cmASEiQA).

Comment: @Adnan I think you should add a 1-byte alias for `vy`, I see it being used a lot.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), <s>104</s> <s>108</s> <s>88</s> 84 bytes

```perl6
{my &f={[*] 1..$_ div 2}
.comb.Bag{*}.&{(2>.grep(*%2))*f(.sum)/[*]($_».&f)%666013}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#bctBCoMwEAXQvacYRMUEOq0Wsgl20WuUIklMooK1VBQk5GTd9U5dW4Uuuuh8PnwezDhomBgPuhkSC8XitmEKd6FXyBCjEqpmgtxzVH0n8Sysox4Tl@YntA99T2mcE0JNisPYkf36lkbl64mJITFj7JAdvV8GMYOFUAm5RoQ8@IKQqtq63X/9ZSGlWlVrY6yt66Zp25Av71u/U0LV@gM)

#### How it works

I can't easily generate all permutations and filter them, even if astronomical run-times are allowed, because Perl 6's built-in `permutations` routine straight-out refuses to permute lists of more than 20 elements and the task description requires inputs of up to 100 characters.

So instead I use a direct formula based on the letter frequencies of the input:

1. ```
   my &f={[*] 1..$_ div 2}
   ```

   A helper function that halves a number and rounds it down to the nearest integer, and then takes the factorial of that.
2. ```
   .comb.Bag{*}.&{    };
   ```

   Tally up the letter frequencies in the input string, and make them the [topic](https://docs.perl6.org/language/variables#The_$__Variable) for the rest of the code.
   E.g. for input `abcdabcdddddd` this would be the list `(2, 2, 2, 7)`.
3. ```
   (2>.grep(*%2))*
   ```

   If there is more than one odd letter frequency, multiply the result by zero, because no palindromes are possible in that case.
4. ```
   f(.sum)/[*]($_».&f)
   ```

   Calculate the number of possible permutations of the characters that will be on "one side" of each palindrome *(which corresponds to a multiset with the multiplicities obtained by halving and flooring the input letter frequencies)*. The formula used is from [this PDF](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~sokratov/2008m150/multiperm.pdf):
   **(n<sub>1</sub>+...+ n<sub>k</sub>)! / (n<sub>1</sub>!⋅...⋅n<sub>k</sub>1)**
   E.g. for input letter frequencies `(2,2,2,7)`, the letters on *one* side of the palindrome form a multiset with multiplicities `(1,1,1,3)`, and the number of permutations is thus `(1+1+1+3)! / (1!⋅1!⋅1!⋅3!) = 120`.
5. ```
   %666013
   ```

   Take the result modulo 666013.

Comment: Good to see that [my alternative](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@3944qGtwQ93zFO0UgxQ4TqywOdR0xoPrsPtR7r1HjXu8Xm4o0kl8fBE1UcNcw5tPbkJKPmoYeb////VE5OSgSgFDNQB) method is valid!

Answer (score 3):

## Python3, <s>81</s> 80 bytes

```
from itertools import*
lambda s:sum(a==a[::-1]for a in{*permutations(s)})%666013
```

This is the shortest I could come up with. Not sure if the permutations can be generated more easily...

### Explanation

```
lambda s:                       # Anonymous function taking a parameter <s>. 
    sum(                        # Sum the following terms.
        a==a[::-1]              # Check whether the permutation <a> is a palindrome,
        for a in                # for each element <a>,
        {                       # inside a set that can only contain distinct elements.
            *                   # Splat the elements of the following object:
            permutations(s)     # the permutations of the input parameter <s>.
        }                       #
    )%666013                    # Modulo the sum by 666013.
```

### Notes

1. The check `a==a[::-1]` returns a boolean value, but the `sum(...)` function implicitly casts it to an integer (0 or 1) and sums accordingly.
2. I have to use the '[splat operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)' (not the real name), to extract the elements from the object `permutations(...)`. Otherwise the set (`{...}`) would contain only one element, the object itself.
3. I use a set (`{...}`) to keep only distinct permutations inside.

In Floroid, this is (almost) `z(T(a==aDKaIW(cb(L)))%666013)`, but prints the result instead, and takes input through the command line.

Thanks to [@Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan) for saving a byte! --> Changed the `import` style

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#DcJRCoMwDADQqxR/TAYO9lvoScYocbMQsE1J4pfs7FXeGyXtVNcfBYt2VKCU6B3j8voU0UCB2/nImWsX9ZxhZt/URXab8dk3rYeTszQDwz@OrtwcCkxfWm80IY4L)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Œ!QŒḂ€S%“µɲ€’
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@390kmLg0UkPdzQ9aloTrPqoYc6hrSc3AdmPGmb@//8/OTEJCBMB)**

#### How?

A brute forcer.

```
Œ!QŒḂ€S%“µɲ€’ - Main link: string
Œ!            - all permutations
  Q           - unique
     €        - for each
   ŒḂ         - isPalindromic? (yep a built-in!)
      S       - sum
       %      - mod
        “µɲ€’ - base 250 compressed number 666013
```

---

I *believe* that **[this](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#DZE7bpRBEIRz38ISXIITEDhA8gn63fOe@R@7ayLjhNghEkIcgAjJkgMim4RjeC@yTDQatbrqq@rL6@PHt@cfL0@31x@uP727@vvz5vzw6@r169vzw@35y5@b@b6D18f35/vvL0//fs/h@f7b5XJZQ@mHkEuW1FPB4EJZtJhEPfYK3O/QQgm8MWykhUt0TIddEsja4wCMhpJpl1CjCjMwhj3ldShCSeR5SbXlWFgosiGwaM5utK8posW1Usa4GXlq6IseF2gFYKcEkaua0uexiaOlZe2LrVKDuGhNkQlhmChaR09O0kLiEcKWiKGgSOsLHYi4Cxshc0@pYtXNQp6QoNOkqq@tIGYVHyWAc4tB5SjBUjyyn0ZcW2LPyrjXBqcpbSmAes7RRpwl@NTCyDFJoxoIkLbgXIAWgi3UtMWiopxkmxQWLS51iaaThAtGbX2KjROrozIdLB4Xd8tEuk10SkGLUrClgSwjeLgDnxbxNDAvYWZXcj9kghCaQudDqDqZdAGsUICrEQWdG9RXMpjhcJ/fcBzzaLLGUdh8rTXlOSEc/TC3R5tuULVtGWdvApTNF0QpsBYoxsssPqVG3GZoMXNvkvaA3g2sA/YcuuQatIsXmU1NlrGicW9xh4aQCQUts@uhlEiZ2VMc/wE)** will do it more efficiently, but it's **30** bytes (edit: [this pdf](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/%7Esokratov/2008m150/multiperm.pdf) seems to confirm it, courtesy of [smls's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110992/53748)):

```
ÑHḞµS!÷!P$ - Link 1, palindrome count: string a    e.g. 'abcabcd'
Ñ          - call the next link (2) as a monad(a)  e.g. [2, 2, 2, 1]
 H         - halve                                 e.g. [1, 1, 1, 0.5]
  Ḟ        - floor (get pair counts)               e.g. [1, 1, 1, 0]
   µ       - start a new monadic chain - call that p
    S      - sum(p)                                e.g. 3
     !     - factorial                             e.g. 6
         $ - last 2 links as a monad:
       !   -     factorial(p) (vectorises)         e.g. [1, 1, 1, 1]
        P  -     product                           e.g. 1
      :    - integer division                      e.g. 6

ĠL€ - Link 2, count characters: string a           e.g. 'abcabcd'
Ġ   - group indexes                                e.g. [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], 7]
 L€ - length of €ach                               e.g. [2, 2, 2, 1]

ÇḂS⁼LḂ$aÑ%“µɲ€’ - Main link: string a              e.g. 'abcabcd'
                - first check to see if any palindromes will be possible:
Ç               - last link (2) as a monad         e.g. [2, 2, 2, 1]
 Ḃ              - mod 2                            e.g. [0, 0, 0, 1]
  S             - sum                              e.g. 1
      $         - last two links as a monad:
    L           -     length(a string)             e.g. 7
     Ḃ          -     mod 2                        e.g. 1
   ⁼            - equal?                           e.g. 1 (1 when palindromes are possible)
       a        - and
        Ñ       - next link as a monad             e.g. 6
         %“µɲ€’ - mod 666013, as in the brute force version.
```

Comment: Yes it does, the `%` is mod.

Comment: Gah, I was just about to post *exactly* this answer, but didn't get there in time because I posted the Brachylog answer first. A matter of second in it, I think. Clearly I should remember that Jelly is a more popular language than Brachylog and so I should work on that submission first.

Comment: Wow, byte for byte? I have another 13 too, but think it's slightly less efficient :)

Comment: Is the number compressed in a different base or what? :P

Comment: From my TIO tab, `Œ!QŒḂ€S%“µɲ€’`. That looks bytewise identical to me.

Comment: @TuukkaX yes it's in base 250 (the bytes inside the quotes).

Comment: Your alternative method doesn't corrently handle inputs with odd letter counts>1 (my answer didn't either in its first revision). E.g. `aadddeee` should produce 0, and `aaddd` should produce 2.

Comment: @smls oops, yes; fixed - I was counting the number of 0.5s in the halved counts rather than counting the number of odd counts. (managed to rearrange for a 0 byte cost too).

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 46 bytes

```
Permutations@#~Count~_?PalindromeQ~Mod~666013&
```

Takes a list of characters as input.

Terribly inefficient, because it actually generates all permutations of the input and then counts the palindromic ones.

Comment: I think this incorrectly gives a positive answer, rather than `0`, if the string has multiple letters occurring with odd multiplicity (like `"abcdabcddddddeee"`).

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks, fixed. This was needlessly complicated anyway.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 68 bytes

```
If[i=Floor[t=Last/@Tally@#/2];Tr[t-i]<1,Multinomial@@i,0]~Mod~666013
```

Pure function taking a list of characters as input and returning an integer. Not as short as [Martin Ender's Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110973/56178), but it's a cute approach nonetheless, which seems to be the same approach as in [smls's Perl 6 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110992/56178).

First, `t=Last/@Tally@#/2` computes the counts of all the distinct characters in the input, divided by `2`; then `i=Floor` rounds down any fractions occurring in `t`. Note that palindromic permutations of the input exist exactly when there is at most one odd number among the original counts, that is, when there is at most one fraction in `t`. We can test for that by simply adding up all the elements of `t-i` (using `Tr`): if the answer is less than `1`, there are palindromic permutations, otherwise not.

If there are, then `i` represents the counts of distinct characters in the left half of the permutations, which can be arranged arbitrarily. The number of ways to do that is exactly the `Multinomial` coefficient (a quotient of certain factorials), which Mathematica has built-in.

Answer (score 1):

## k, 23 bytes

```
{666013!+/{x~|x}'cmb x}
```

If using [oK](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/), or `cmb` doesn't exist, use `prm` instead of `cmb`.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 15 bytes

```
%l{_I#.pQ666013
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%25l%7B_I%23.pQ666013&input=%22cababaa%22&debug=0).

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <strike>67</strike> <strike>57</strike> <strike>52</strike> 59 chars

```
->s{s.chars.permutation.uniq.count{|t|t.reverse==t}%666013}
```

Comment: Codegolf submissions should be [proper programs/functions/lambdas, not snippets](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2422/14880). I'm not a Ruby programmer, but I think you can turn this into a lambda by wrapping it in `->s{  }`, can't you?

Comment: Also, based on the [documentation](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/permutation), isn't the `(s.size)` argument redundant?

Comment: I tested it on Ruby 2.4, and it works without the `.to_a` too.

Comment: @smls Doesn't work on ruby 2.3.3 (`undefined method `uniq' for #<Enumerator`), but right it works on ruby 2.4, thanks :)

Comment: Does the result have to be taken `mod 666013`?

Comment: @NonlinearFruit I guess yes, it just doesn't make sense why such a random number

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <strike>20</strike> 18 bytes

```
á f_¥Zw} l %666013
```

Saved 2 bytes thanks to ETHproductions.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@394oUJa/KGlUeW1CjkKqmZmZgaGxv//KyUnJgFhohIA)

Comment: Nice, that's what I would have done. You can save two bytes with `f_¥Zw}` , as `_` is short for `Z{Z`

Comment: `á fêS â l %666013` would save you a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## C++14, 161 bytes

As unnamed lambda assuming input is like `std::string` and returning via reference parameter.

```cpp
#import<algorithm>
[](auto s,int&n){auto a=s.begin(),b=s.end();std::sort(a,b);n=0;do n=(n+std::equal(a,b,s.rbegin()))%666013;while(std::next_permutation(a,b));}
```

Ungolfed and usage:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

#import<algorithm>
auto f=
[](auto s,int&n){
 auto a=s.begin(),b=s.end();
 std::sort(a,b);
 n=0;
 do
  n=(n+std::equal(a,b,s.rbegin()))%666013;
 while(std::next_permutation(a,b));
}
;

using namespace std;


int main(){
 string s;
 s = "cababaa";
 s = "abcdabcddddd";
 int n;
 f(s,n);
 cout << n << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## MATL, 13 bytes

```
Y@Xu!"@tP=Avs
```

Try it at [**MATL Online**](https://matl.io/?code=Y%40Xu%21%22%40tP%3DAvs&inputs=%27cababaa%27&version=19.8.0)

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly grab input as a string
Y@      % Compute all permutations of the inputs (one per row)
Xu      % Determine the unique rows
!       % Take the transpose so each permutation is a column
"       % For each unique permutation
  @     % Take this permutation
  tP=A  % Duplicate it, reverse it, and compare (yields 1 for palindrome and 0 otherwise)
  v     % Vertically concatenate the entire stack
  s     % Compute the sum of all elements
        % Implicitly end for loop and display the result
```

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 19 bytes

```
qe!{_W%=}%:+666013%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@YqlgdH65qW6tqpW1mZmZgaKz6/39yYhIQJgIA)

Explanation:

```
qe!{_W%=}%:+666013% e# Full program.
q                   e# Get all input.
 e!                 e# Get all unique permutations.
   {_W%=}           e# Function to check if a list is a palindrome.
    _               e# Duplicate ToS.
     W%             e# Reverse ToS (Push -1, Modular index of ToS).
       =            e# Check if ToS is equal to SToS.
         %          e# Map.
          :+        e# Sum (Reduce by addition).
            666013  e# Push 666013.
                  % e# Modulo.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ohm, 17 bytes

```
I⌐:_₧?¡;;¼,
```

Explanation:

```
I⌐:_₧?¡;;¼,  ■Main wire
I⌐:     ;    ■for _ in permutations(input()){
   _₧? ;     ■  if(palindrome(_)){
      ¡      ■    counter++;
       ;     ■  }
        ;    ■}
         ¼,  ■print(counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 182 Bytes

```
function f($a,$b=1){return$a?f($a-1,bcmul($a,$b)):$b;}$a=count_chars($argv[1],$r=1);foreach($a as$v){$c+=$v%2?:0;$c>1?die("0"):$z+=$f=$v/2^0;$r=bcmul(f($f),$r);}echo bcdiv(f($z),$r);
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9f6004ed96b613b75b61404b22f531af0d80a253)

### Breakdown

```
function f($a,$b=1){  #Factorial
    return$a?f($a-1,bcmul($a,$b)):$b;
}
$a=count_chars($argv[1],$r=1); # Array count for every char
foreach($a as$v){
    $c+=$v%2?:0; # counter mod 2 ==1
    $c>1?die("0"):$z+=$f=$v/2^0; # end program if there are 2 chars which cannot divide by 2
    $r=bcmul(f($f),$r);
}
echo bcdiv(f($z),$r);
```